# Batch where command from a network share not seeing local C

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a bat script that is simply trying to find an exe in the user that launches it local C drive the code it as follows:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where /r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server" bcp.exe') do set output=%%i
if "%output%"=="" (
   for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where /r "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" bcp.exe') do set output=%%i
)
echo %output%
```

When run from a local directory on the users machine, %output% will have a valid path.  The issue however is to have it available to everyone this script lives on a network share that is mapped to everyone's machine (L:\ Drive).

So if the script is called from the command line locally:

```
C:\Test>findBCP.bat
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe
```

But if run from L:\

```
L:\Shared Scripts>findBCP.bat
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
%i
```

EDITED:
After countless efforts here I tried this again after closing all cmd sessions and cleaning up my %PATH%, which shouldn't have mattered, I reconnected to the network share and tried to re-run and everything seems fine. Not sure why though.

Comment: Impossible. Given script contains **absolute paths** `where /r "C:\Prog…`. Hence, it _must_ give the same results regardless of where it's launched from. Is `type "L:\Shared Scripts\findBCP.bat"` the same as `type "C:\Test\findBCP.bat"`?

Comment: What about extending your script by `where /R "L:\Shared Scripts" bcp.exe`?

Comment: @JosefZ The script is exactly the same saved as a bat file and called from this directories.  The L drive is a mapped network share that lives on another server "\\serverShare\Share\Shared Scripts" and it's possible because I'm getting it lol

Comment: @aschipfl - Adding a where check isn't valid there is no BCP.exe in that path

Comment: Since you seem to have your problem solved and you cannot reproduce it anyway, I suggest you delete your question, as it might not be that helpful for future readers...

Answer (score 1):

If you know the alternative pathes there is no need for the `/R` option of where, the following batch should do:

```
@echo off
Set "PRG=C:\Program Files"
Set "MSS=Microsoft SQL Server"
Set "Exe=bcp.exe"

Set "Search=%PRG%\%MSS%;%PRG% (x86)\%MSS%:%Exe%"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where "%Search%"') do set output=%%i
echo %output%
```

Comment: How does this consider both paths? It just looks like you parameterized the x86 path and never look in the non x86 path?

Comment: @S.G. Look at the var Search it compounds both pathes separated with a semicolon. See where /? for the syntax.

Comment: Ah, nice it shrinks things down nicely.